# CSS3 double drop border?

Tags: css, border

Ok, so I wish to create something like http://i.imgur.com/jox0ENW.jpg. But be of a modular type, where I might have a button class that'll make it look like that, and a class I can use to apply to sections.

Right now I have:

```
.double-drop {
    position: relative;

    padding: map-get($padding, xl);
    margin-top: (-1 * 280px);

    border: 3px solid $black;

    background-color: $white;

    &:before {
        content: '';

        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;

        top: (-1 * map-get($padding, m));
        right: (-1 * map-get($padding, m));

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        border: 3px solid $black;

        background-color: $lighter-grey;
    }
}
```

Which works, and creates that effect on sections. But not if the section is inside a parent which is absolutely positioned. (the drop shadow goes behind..)

I would like to imitate that effect in the image, for all my buttons, and obviously transition its translate so it moves or what not.

Would it be possible first of all?

Comment: Please demo the issue..ideally in a JSfiddle.net example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Multiple Borders on CSS Only Button

Perhaps using multiple shadows as borders would be a simple solution? It degrades gracefully in browsers that don't support it, and it's easy to work with.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/ats1rtxf/)

```
.shadow-button {
padding:10px;
border:solid 3px #000000;
display:inline-block; /* used only to shrink wrap the div around the contents, has a default margin */
-webkit-box-shadow:8px -8px 0px -2px #cccccc, 8px -8px 0px 1px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow:8px -8px 0px -2px #cccccc, 8px -8px 0px 1px #000000;
box-shadow:8px -8px 0px -2px #cccccc, 8px -8px 0px 1px #000000;
font-family:Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;    
}

p {padding:10px;}
```

---

```
<div class="shadow-button">PLAY MUSIC VIDEO</div>
```

Browser Support: http://caniuse.com/#search=box